# using event handler

Tags: c++, c, events, mouse, bgi

is there a way to use mouse as an event handler in c/c++ im making a game on snakes and ladder (the famous board game) and trying to make it with basic borland c++ compiler working with a header file called graphics.h, which is very basic and gives output of 640 X 480 res, so I was wondering if there is a possiblity of using mouse as an  event handler (about which i have no experiance)to have control over the palyer coins on the board.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure which version of graphics.h you happen to have, but there are functions `getmousey`, `getmousey`, `clearmouseclick` and `getmouseclick`.  [See this](http://www.stefansundin.se/programmering/proga/WINBGIM-%20MANUAL.pdf) for some documentation that may work for you.

It appeas that you can use `registermousehandler` and a call-back function to do some level of event-based programming.  Here's a sample from the document I sent you.

```
// The click_handler will be called whenever the left mouse button is
// clicked. It checks copies the x,y coordinates of the click to
// see if the click was on a red pixel. If so, then the boolean
// variable red_clicked is set to true. Note that in general
// all handlers should be quick. If they need to do more than a little
// work, they should set a variable that will trigger the work going,
// and then return.
bool red_clicked = false;
void click_handler(int x, int y)
{
    if (getpixel(x,y) == RED)
    red_clicked = true;
}

// Call this function to draw an isosoles triangle with the given base and
// height. The triangle will be drawn just above the botton of the screen.
void triangle(int base, int height)
{
    int maxx = getmaxx( );
    int maxy = getmaxy( );
    line(maxx/2 - base/2, maxy - 10, maxx/2 + base/2, maxy - 10);
    line(maxx/2 - base/2, maxy - 10, maxx/2, maxy - 10 - height);
    line(maxx/2 + base/2, maxy - 10, maxx/2, maxy - 10 - height);
}
void main(void)
{
    int maxx, maxy; // Maximum x and y pixel coordinates
    int divisor; // Divisor for the length of a triangle side
    // Put the machine into graphics mode and get the maximum coordinates:
    initwindow(450, 300);
    maxx = getmaxx( );
    maxy = getmaxy( );
    // Register the function that handles a left mouse click
    registermousehandler(WM_LBUTTONDOWN, click_handler);
    // Draw a white circle with red inside and a radius of 50 pixels:
    setfillstyle(SOLID_FILL, RED);
    setcolor(WHITE);
    fillellipse(maxx/2, maxy/2, 50, 50);
    // Print a message and wait for a red pixel to be double clicked:
    settextstyle(DEFAULT_FONT, HORIZ_DIR, 2);
    outtextxy(20, 20, "Left click in RED to end.");
    setcolor(BLUE);
    red_clicked = false;
    divisor = 2;
    while (!red_clicked)
    {
        triangle(maxx/divisor, maxy/divisor);
        delay(500);
        divisor++;
    }
    cout << "The mouse was clicked at: ";
    cout << "x=" << mousex( );
    cout << " y=" << mousey( ) << endl;
    // Switch back to text mode:
    closegraph( );
}
```

Comment: i am not sure which version of graphics.h i am using but are thre these fuctions getmousey defined in the header file, and what does it do ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Mouse and Keyboard events using Win32 Programming (In Visual Studio).

Is it the requirement to use borland c++.

I think similar APIs are there in borland c++.

You can refer http://www.functionx.com/win32/index.htm for more information on event handling in Visual Studio using Win32 Programming.